# php this variable

Tags: php

I have found this line in a php book is it right? I do not know if the '`this->objects[key]`' is like this.

Here is the line:

```
this->objects[ $key ] = new $object( $this);
```

Is this a mistake by the author? I am talking about the 'this' variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the author just forgot the dollar sign in front of the $this variable.

Answer (score 1):

What's the concrete question? What "should" be wrong with that line of code?

Syntactically, it looks correct, except for one small thing: It should read `$this` instead of `this`.

This is what happens in this line: You have an instance attribute `$this->objects` of type `array`. The value entry identified by `$key` is initialized (or updated) by assigning a new object of class `$object` to it. The concrete name of that class is encoded (as a string) in the `$object` variable. For example: `$object = 'MyCustomer'` would result in `new MyCustomer($this)`. A parameter (`$this`) is passed to the constructor, but that is another story and, as I assume, not subject of the current problem.

Maybe, hopefully, that is what you are asking for: `new $object(...)` means, for example, `new MyCustomer(...)`. If not, I didn't get the point of your problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

should be `$this`, not `this`.

let's hope it wasn't one of my books ;-)